# Is it possible to add an extension to an outbound call via Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am currently working on implementing Amazon Connect at our company as their call center solution. We work with alot of clients that have internal extensions on a main line. The agent control panel allows for placing external calls however, there isnt a way to add an extension to the phone number automatically (or programatically) as far as I can tell. At the very base of it, I am wondering, is it possible to add a "pause" or "wait" to a call placed via the Connect CCP or through the use of Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

When you make outbound call the destination number is of the E.164 format. Adding exention to E.164 format is as below.

> "+19995556789;ext=12345"

Where 12345 is an extension.

More documentation on the StartOutboundVoiceContact,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartOutboundVoiceContact.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this applicable only to the API? Can this be dialed via the agent CCP?